# How do you redirect URLs with a query string to another page?

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, redirect, http-redirect

This htaccess snippet is supposed to redirect

mywebsite.com/product-category/clothing/?orderby=popularity

to

mywebsite.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/\?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true$ http://alt.myhost.com/?p=$1&preview=true [NC,R=301,L]
```

but for some reason I can't escape the / and ? part of the URL. Not sure why this isnt working...

I've tried escaping?

```
\\? \? [?]
```

and I've tried escaping the /

```
\\/ \/ [/]
```

none of these seem to work either...

help!

Answer (score 1):

Anything after `?` in url is part of URL QueryString.

You can not test url QueryString in pattern of a RewriteRule. you need to  match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in `RewriteCond` directive  something the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^orderby=popularty$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-category/clothing/?$ http://example.com/?  [NC,R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `http://mywebsite.com/product-category/clothing/?orderby=popularty` to `http://example.com/` .

The empty questions mark at the end of the destination url (http://example.com/?) is important as it discards the old querystring from the destination path/url .

Comment: how will redirect **http://mywebsite.com/?orderby=price to ?orderby=price**
@starkeen

Comment: Aren't `/?orderby=price` and `/?orderby=price` similar uris?

Comment: hey sorry, it was typo mistake, how will redirect mywebsite.com/?orderby=price to mywebsite.com @starkeen